# SQL counter flag is not filtered

Tags: sql, ora-01722

I'm using SQL developer and I'm getting an error I don't fully understand.

Due to data privacy, I cannot share the real query, but the question is fairly simple.

I have a query to obtain table T (which works if ran alone) and I want to filter a Y/N flag so I have the following query:

`select * from T where flag ='Y'`

While this query works, I want the observations which do not fullfil the condition but neither of the following queries works:

`select * from T where flag <>'Y'`

`select * from T where flag ='N'`

*I get the following error:
01722. 00000 - "invalid number"
*Cause: The specified number was invalid.
*Action: Specify a valid number .
Vendor code 1722*

I tried to export the table to analyze it on another language, but I still get the same error.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is `T` truly a table, not a view?

Comment: `T` results of left joins and inner joins of tables. I use case whens to obtain de flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you confirmed `T` in your example is not a table, your error simply seems to be caused by a conversion error somewhere on 1 or several records `WHERE flag <> 'Y'`. This is why the query works with `flag = 'Y'` but not with your other conditions.

Minimal case to reproduce would be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    Field VARCHAR(10),
    Flag VARCHAR(1)
);
CREATE VIEW T AS SELECT to_number(Field), Flag FROM MyTable;
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('1', 'Y'); /* OK */
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ('No way', 'N'); /* Fails */
```

In your case, the error may not be caused by a call to `to_number` but this is the best clue I can give given the limited information you provide. It might not be a call to a function at all but the result of a calculation using operators only.

You simply need to make sure the fields can be converted/used in a calculation before you actually attempt to do so (`CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE NULL` for instance).

Comment: Thank you for your answer as it was useful to solving my problem. Turns out somewhere in the joins, one variable was a character and the other a number, but sql didn't trigger an error when the table was created. Only when I was filtering the table.

Comment: Yes, because you do an operation somewhere that is valid and the DBMS trusts you on that one. The only way it has to warn you about the potential error would be to test all the records one by one when you define your view / stored procedure as well as testing it again on every insert and update, which costs too much performance to be feasible.